# Why tooltip is not working for option tag of select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using uib-tooltip-html for displaying tooltip when someone hovers over options of select tag. But its not working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<select id="repeatSelect" ng-model="$root.selectedClusterOption" class="cluster-options btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ng-change="header.goToClusterPage()">
  <option value="allClusters" ng-selected="$root.selectedClusterOption === 'allClusters'" uib-tooltip="All Clusters" tooltip-placement="auto bottom-left">All Clusters</option>
  <option ng-repeat="cluster in [{cluster_id: 1, cluster_name: 'cluster 1'}]" value="{{cluster.cluster_id}}" ng-selected="$root.selectedClusterOption === '{{cluster.cluster_id}}'" uib-tooltip-html="'{{cluster.cluster_name}}'" tooltip-placement="auto bottom">{{cluster.cluster_name}}</option>
 </select>
```